# Regex trouble capturing everything before last letter or number

Tags: regex

I want to capture everything before the last letter or number. I do not want to match any white space, "-", or "#013" after the last letter or number.

This is the regex I currently have but it seems to be matching everything

```
(?<system_name>.*\w(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]))



Current data:
469869-system 
476657-SYSTEM 
476657-system 
681125-system#013
981765-system#013
687755-system#013
438105-system#013
281055-system#013
485548-SYSTEM 
785455-system 
489418-system 
589568-system 
489661-SYSTEM 
486328-system -  - #015
286728-system -  - #015
SYSTEM-433455 
system

What I want to match:
469869-system 
476657-SYSTEM 
476657-system 
681125-system
981765-system
687755-system
438105-system
281055-system
485548-SYSTEM 
785455-system 
489418-system 
589568-system 
489661-SYSTEM 
486328-system
286728-system
SYSTEM-433455 
system
```

Comment: What language/tool are you using? From the [regex tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info): "Since regular expressions are not fully standardized, all questions with this tag should also include a tag specifying the applicable programming language or tool."

Comment: Is [this](https://regex101.com/r/yxXaNJ/1) working for you?

Comment: Yes it did thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
^[\w-]+
```

where:

- `^` # beginning of line
- `[\w-]+` # character class, 1 or more word character or hyphen

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/yxXaNJ/1)